# Argparse Arg with > flag

Tags: python, argparse, flags

I have a commandline script that works perfectly fine. Now I want to make my tool more intuitive.

I have:

```
parser.add_argument("-s",help = "'*.sam','*.fasta','*.fastq'", required=True)
```

right now, `python script.py -s savefile.sam` works but I would like it to be `python script.py > savefile.sam`

```
parser.add_argument("->",help = "'*.sam','*.fasta','*.fastq'", required=True)
```

does not work as it gives: `error: unrecognized arguments: -`

can I do this with argparse or should I settle for `-s`?

Comment: `> savefile.sam` looks like **shell syntax**. It makes your command line *less* intuitive as using it would require using shell syntax escapes.

Comment: I'd *definitely* settle for sticking to `-` for options, that's the convention.

Comment: …(just adding to the first comment) and since the shell syntax has priority it won't even work.

Comment: if it is possible to make it work with `python script.py > savefile.sam` that would be more intuitive. if I can get it to work but only with shell escapes then you are right and then I should settle for `-s`

Comment: `>` is interpreted by the shell, it does not even pass to Python. It redirects `stdout` into a file. As such, you just need to output to `stdout`, done.

Comment: this is exactly the answer I did not want to hear. But I am glad you confirmed I should stick with -s. this will save me hours of trial and error only to be disappointed in the end. Thank you guys!

Comment: or put the `>` in quotes like `'>'`

Comment: @Skaperen that is something I already tried, and failed to do.

Answer (score 4):

`> savefile.sam` is shell syntax and means "send output to the file savefile.sam".  Argparse won't even see this part of the command because the shell will interpret it first (assuming you issue this command from a suitable shell).

While your command does make sense, you shouldn't try to use `argparse` to implement it.  Instead, if an `-s` isn't detected, simply send the script's output to `stdout`.  You can achieve this by setting the default for `-s`:

```
parser.add_argument("-s",
                    type=argparse.FileType("w"),
                    help="'*.sam','*.fasta','*.fastq'",
                    default=sys.stdout)
```

This way, you can run `python script.py > savefile.sam`, and the following will happen:

1. The shell will evaluate `python script.py`.
2. `argparse` will see no additional arguments, and will use the default `sys.stdout`.
3. Your script will send output to `stdout`.
4. The shell will redirect the script's output from `stdout` to `savefile.sam`.

Of course, you can also send the `stdout` of the script into the `stdin` the another process using a [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29).

Note that, using `FileType`, it's also legal to use  `-s -` to specify `stdout`.  See [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) for details.

Comment: I will make `required=False` `required=True` and stick with the -s option. If I am correct, the argparse FileType instantly opens the file. and that is something that should not be done in my case (these files are 50GB+)

Comment: @zazga: Opening a file does not read its contents into memory :)  Either way, you needn't use `FileType` if you don't want to – just check `args.s` whenever it's appropriate and decide what to do (either print to `stdout` or write to file).

Comment: learning every day! what is faster, writing to file or print to stdout?

Comment: It depends what you're doing.  If you give the file directly to the program using `-s`, then your code can seek through the file (it can't do this if it's writing to `stdout`).  This may or may not be an advantage to you.  However, the example code that I provided has the advantage that you can either pass a file directly to the program **or** use shell redirection, depending on your preference.  Either way, I don't think you'll see much difference unless your code's performance is limited by how quickly it can write its output to disk.

Comment: then I will just stick with whatever works! thanks for your input though

Answer (score 0):

In a sense your `argparse` works

```
import argparse
import sys
print sys.argv
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('->')
print parser.parse_args('-> test'.split())
print parser.parse_args()
```

with no arguments, it just assigns `None` to the `>` attribute.  Note though that you can't access this attribute as `args.>`.  You'd have to use `getattr(args,'>')` (which is what `argparse` uses internally).  Better yet, assign this argument a proper long name or dest.

```
1401:~/mypy$ python stack29233375.py
['stack29233375.py']
Namespace(>='test')
Namespace(>=None)
```

But if I give a `-> test` argument, the shell redirection consumes the `>`, as shown below:

```
1405:~/mypy$ python stack29233375.py -> test
usage: stack29233375.py [-h] [-> >]
stack29233375.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -
1408:~/mypy$ cat test
['stack29233375.py', '-']
Namespace(>='test')
```

Only the `-` passes through in `argv`, and on to the parser.  So it complains about unrecognized arguments.  An optional positional argument could have consumed this string, resulting in no errors.

Notice that I had to look at the `test` file to see the rest of the output - because the shell redirected `stdout` to `test`.  The error message goes to `stderr`, so it doesn't get redirected.

You can change the prefix char from `-` (or in addition to it) with an `ArgumentParser` parameter.  But you can't use such a character alone.  The flag must be `prefix + char` (i.e. 2 characters).

Finally, since this argument is required, do you even need a flag?  Just make it a positional argument.  It's quite common for scripts to take input and/or output file names as positional arguments.

Comment: I have been thinking about making it a positional argument and I came up with a reason why not to. But that was yesterday and today It doesn't come to mind again so I think I should just go for it!
thanks for `getattr(args,'>')` saved me a lot of head scratching. I already used a long name